# error 1064 mysql (42000) when omitting a semicolon in `if then ; else ; end if`

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if ;
end' at line 18
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UnitIdCheckForDelete( 
p_unitId varchar(50))
begin
if(
   (
    (
     SELECT ifnull(count(tbl_Product.unitId),0) 
     FROM  tbl_Product 
     WHERE   unitId=p_unitId
    ) > 0
   ) OR 
   (
    (
     SELECT ifnull(count(tbl_UnitConversion.unitId),0) 
     FROM tbl_UnitConversion 
     WHERE  tbl_UnitConversion.unitId=p_unitId
    ) > 0 
   )  
  )
then
SELECT 'true' ;
else
SELECT 'false'
end if ;
end ; //
```

Comment: Okay. And your problem is?

Comment: Try adding a bit more text to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UnitIdCheckForDelete( 
p_unitId varchar(50))
begin
if(
   ((SELECT ifnull(count(tbl_Product.unitId),0) 
     FROM  tbl_Product 
     WHERE   unitId=p_unitId)>0) OR 
    ((SELECT ifnull(count(tbl_UnitConversion.unitId),0) 
      FROM tbl_UnitConversion 
      WHERE  tbl_UnitConversion.unitId=p_unitId)> 0 )  
    )
then SELECT 'true' ;
else SELECT 'false' ;
end if ;
end ; //
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `semicolun` at the end of your following statement,

```
SELECT 'false'
```

This statement should be like:(as @nrathaus has mentioned in his comments)

```
SELECT 'false';
```

Comment: @nrathaus sorry but, I didn't get your edit friend

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the problem, I dont' want to downvote my upvote, I believe he is missing a `)`

Comment: There is no extra bracket.. that is just closing of sp paramaters

Comment: Why is that extra braces a problem? it is not see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @nrathaus I think i get it wrong, You give the answer I will upvote it, and will delete this.

Comment: I think the issue is the delimiter, as noted below, as `;` is the default delimiter

Comment: @nrathaus you are right.